# What is the adjoint of $TT^*$ when $T$ is closable and both $T$ and $TT^*$ are densely defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $T$ is a densely defined (unclosed) closable operator such that $TT^*$ too is densely defined, is it true that $(TT^*)^*=\overline{T}T^*$? If this is untrue, what if $T$ is assumed to be symmetric?

Many thanks.